# EXC_BAD_ACCESS at UISearchBar that work at ios5 but not at ios4?

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, exc-bad-access, uisearchbar

```
- (void)reset{
    searchList.text=@"";
    SearchNear.text=@"";
    [BNUtilitiesQuick ListController].searchBar1.text=@"";
    [self ResignSearchFirstResponder];
}
```

this code is work at IOS-5 but why this code is error at IOS-4, and always said like "EXC_BAD_ACCESS", I have looked another question but I don't find the answer, I already enable zombie detection by setting the environment variable NSZombieEnabled to YES, but I can't find the error, any one can help me to fix it? I want my application run at IOS-4 too

Comment: Oh never mind then. So we can't talk about bugs in IOs 5 openly?

Comment: Well I am not 100% sure, but as the iOS 5 beta is still available on the developer portal and is not out for public release, that the NDA will likely still apply.

Comment: I just want to confirm that the best way to handle it is to wait till xcode 4.2 is out of beta. Or perhaps, there is a special apple forum for developer to report bugs, etc.

Comment: Curiously it works at the iPhone

Comment: @Jim Thio - Could you supply more details please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the new features of iOS 5 are still under NDA, it isn't a giant secret mentioning it. That being said, the beta versions of XCode are usually pretty buggy during that time. I would probably trust what is coming out of your standard version before I would trust the iOS 5. And I am speaking from experience.

Best case scenario is to have the beta installed on a 2nd machine and you can go back and forth.

For issues specific to your code, I would check the beta forums in the developer portal. You should be able to openly talk shop there. Good luck.